# Json ColumnType SystemInvalidOperationException

Tags: npgsql

I am using npgql v3.1.8 and EntityFramework6.Npgsql v3.1.1 using code first database creation.

I would like to store certain user definable settings in a column using a postgres json field. So the first step is to create a simple model with the column type as text to start with.

```
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Settings { get; set; }
```

This works and allows json to be stored in the column - great, but not using the json postgres column type. Now I drop the database so it can be recreated fresh, and change the model to:

```
    [Column(TypeName = "json")] 
    public string Settings { get; set; }
```

That being the only change, all should be well with the world. But alas an error occurs whilst the model  is being created (and hence the database is never created). The error is:

```
   System.InvalidOperatiopnException: Sequence contains no matching elements
```

Hmm, ok, lets try another method. Remove the attribute and add the below to the DbContext OnModelCreating override:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Equipment>().Property(p => p.Settings).HasColumnType("json");
```

And.. The same error. Anyone encountered this before? For now I am going back to my arbitrary length string column - at least that works!